# Ag-grid initializing grid with thousands of columns

Tags: ag-grid

I am initilizing a grid that contains more than a few thousand columns. The columns are defined by a user of my system and there is no limit to what they can define.

The performance is extremely slow. Approximately 5 minutes for the grid to render. Is there an alternative that I can do to enhance the rendering of the table?

It appears as though the columns go through a method called recursivelyCreateColumns which in my case gets called thousands of times.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you show some code please

Comment: welcome to [so], please go through how to create [mcve]

Comment: The code isn't anything special. We initialize the grid using

 new Grid(eGridDiv: HTMLElement, gridOptions: GridOptions, params?: GridParams): Grid

the params argument contains the column definitions which in my case have thousands of columns.

Comment: Similar question, also mostly unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182683/ag-grid-large-dataset-render-time-slow. You may have better luck asking here: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues, but try to provide a test case that shows the problem. Nobody wants to debug a problem when they have to make their own test case. Unfortunately, they are not very responsive to issues at the moment, they are very busy and are prioritising their paid support (I think).