# Find Javascript code that freezes UI when loading aggrid in a angular application

Tags: angular, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, ag-grid

I am using Angular 6 and aggrid to display a larger dataset with > 500 columns which shouldn't be a problem.
When loading the grid with Chrome it takes a moment but it doesnt freeze the UI. You can still click and drag on the website. Firefox on the other hand freezes completely for nearly 5s. I can't figure out which code is causing this.

Is there a way to monitor what is causing this? Maybe with the firefox devtools?

Comment: Try the [Performance panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance/How_to) in devtools ([video](https://youtu.be/WBmttwfA_k8)).

Comment: I have been using that but with all the angular abstractions its nearly impossible to figure out what the problem is. Is there a way to see the stack trace of blocking functions?

Comment: Your problem could be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977410/ag-grid-initializing-grid-with-thousands-of-columns#comment88977219_50977410. Probably you would start having the same problem even in Chrome if you had even more columns (a few thousand). There's still no answer for it, there's probably some `O(n^2)` or worse code in ag-grid that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks that actually looks a lot like what my issue is. Thx